# right stucture of link to better PR of homepage

Tags: seo, pagerank

I heard that for better PR of the homepage the site needs to be structured like this :

1. the homepage links to all pages, and every single page links to the homepage.
2. the homepage links to second level pages and they links to third level pages, and every single page links to only one upper level page.

my questions is :
1. is it right ?
2. if site designed that every page links to all pages (with sidebar etc.), is it smart to make all extraneous links *rel=nofollow* ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Not really - PageRank (PR) is a
   factor of incoming links. What you
   have described above is more of a PR
   distribution recommendation.
2. rel=nofollow for PR sculpting has
   [been debunked](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/pagerank-sculpting/), by Google, as a
   wasted practice. You should only use
   nofollow on links that you can't
   vouch for. This normally means not
   no-following your own internal
   links.

If you want to increase the PR of your homepage, the only REAL way of doing this is by getting backlinks to that page. from other sites.

Answer (score 1):

This is vaguely right in theory.  In my long practice of doing SEO, I almost came up with this rule of thumb: "to get good Page Rank (say what you will about it not mattering) you have to worry less about SEO and more about making your business as good as it can be.  If that happens, the high-quality links and higher page rank will come.

Regarding the no-follow tag - it is 95% obsolete. I would not focus on it.  Only google ever paid attention to it, and they have their own internal metrics which decide whether a link should be followed or not.

You should cross-link your pages, but not excessively, and try to make your site look natural to the search engines.